# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Magento error log

Tags: php, xml, magento, error-handling, magento-1.7

```
2014-02-11T11:12:15+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /var/www/magento/app/code/local/Bintime/Sinchimport/Block/Layer/View.php on line 19
2014-02-11T11:12:17+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: bgHandle  in /var/www/magento/app/code/community/Magehouse/Slider/Block/Catalog/Layer/Filter/Price.php on line 457
2014-02-11T11:12:17+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: bgSlider  in /var/www/magento/app/code/community/Magehouse/Slider/Block/Catalog/Layer/Filter/Price.php on line 461
2014-02-11T11:12:17+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: bgRange  in /var/www/magento/app/code/community/Magehouse/Slider/Block/Catalog/Layer/Filter/Price.php on line 465
```

I've been in the process of clearing the old error log and this one has got me stuck. I can't tell which file is causing the issue if any. The 4 errors above always pop up in concession so it might be a plugin/theme conflict. The first line is referring to the following plugin:

http://bit.ly/1dfpIID

And the other three are pointing toward what I believe is the price slider that comes with the theme on product pages.

Link to dev site: http://bit.ly/1mAxK2a

The site is running Magento 1.8.1 with a theme called metro store from themeforest.

Here is View.php:

```
<?php

class Bintime_Sinchimport_Block_Layer_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View
{

    protected $filterableFeatures = array();

    /**
     * Prepare child blocks
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        //получение списка фич, по которым строися навигация
        $filterableFeatures = $this->getLayer()->getFilterableFeatures();
        $filterBlockName = 'sinchimport/layer_filter_feature'; //block
        foreach ($filterableFeatures as $feature) {
            $this->filterableFeatures[] = $feature;
            $featureBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($filterBlockName)
                    ->setLayer($this->getLayer())
                    ->setAttributeModel($feature)
                    ->init();
            $this->setChild('feature_' . $feature['feature_id'] . '_filter',
                            $featureBlock
                           );
        }
/* ------------ */
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Get all layer filters
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFilters()
    {
        $filters = parent::getFilters();
/* ------------ */     
        foreach ($this->filterableFeatures as $feature) {
            $filters[] = $this->getChild('feature_' . $feature['feature_id'] . '_filter');
        }       
/* ------------ */

        return $filters;
    }
}
```

And here is Price.php:

http://pastebin.com/BCyFxCe7

Does anybody know what these errors mean or how to fix them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means you're passing something to foreach that is not an array.

You have to validate before:

```
if (count($array) > 0 && is_array($array)) {
   foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
      //code here
   }
}
```

[EDIT]
In your code "foreach ($filterableFeatures as $feature)" and "foreach ($this->filterableFeatures as $feature)" have no protection.

Answer (score 2):

On line 16, this method is returning a string, either an empty string or with string data in it:

```
$filterableFeatures = $this->getLayer()->getFilterableFeatures();
```

I'd recommend trying to troubleshoot that issue first to see why it's not returning anything, but a quick workaround would be to check to see if it's an array before you try running the foreach:

```
if (is_array($filterableFeatures)) {
    foreach ($filterableFeatures as $feature) {
```

Of course, since this is not the root of the problem, this will probably break other things, so definitely try to find the source of the problem first.  I'm guessing that 'Price.php' is erroring out on account of 'View.php'.  So if you fix 'View.php', you'll probably also end up fixing 'Price.php'.